# error while changing the background color of a particular block in beamer how to use it?

Tags: beamer, color, texstudio

[image: want to change the background color red]

```
\begin{block}{ }
    \begin{itemize}{}\scriptsize
        \item[($-$)] abcd
        \item[($-$)] dasdw  
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}


\begin{block}{ }
        \begin{itemize}{}\scriptsize
            \item[($-$)] abcd
            \item[($-$)] dasdw  
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
```

I have two block want to change the background color of a single block. In this phase other block should not get affected.
I tried with defining with a new variable still errors are there

```
\newenvironment{variableblock}[3]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{#2}
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{#3}
  \begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}

\begin{variableblock}{Title}{bg=blue,fg=white}{bg=green,fg=red}
  Body
\end{variableblock}
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? When I try the code from your second fragment it works as expected, without errors. Of course I did put a bit of document structure around it, maybe the problem is there. Can you make a complete document that fails, starting with `\documentclass{beamer}`, then the new block definition, then the document itself with a frame in it using the new block? This would make it easier to find out where the problem is.